# How to have nested avro schema for confluent schema registry?

Tags: avro, confluent-platform

I tried different things with the following web ui
https://schema-registry-ui.landoop.com

I couldn't seem to put the following into the registry:

```
{
    "namespace": "test.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "test",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "field1", 
            "type": "string" 
        },
        {
            "name": "field2",  
            "type": "record", 
            "fields":[
                {"name": "field1", "type": "string" },
                {"name": "field2",  "type": "string"},
                {"name": "intField", "type": "int"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, is there a way to refer to another schema from inside the current one to create a compound/nested schema?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example at

https://github.com/Landoop/schema-registry-ui/issues/43

You need to define schema as an array - with the 1st element the nested record
and as a 2nd element the main avro record